# Horizontal/Vertical scaling of self hosted integration runtime

Tags: azure, ado, azure-data-factory

We're looking for *automated* way to horizontally, vertically scale the pull of self hosted integration runtime virtual machines used in ADF.

Reading Microsoft docs  does not provide answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have the experience, so I can only give you a theoretical answer, but maybe it's helpfull for you.

AFAIK, neither way is configurable out-of-the-box. For scale-out you'll have to deploy an additional IR machine yourself. So probably you'll want to create an image that you can provision from docker or kubernetes and has the IR and pre-requirements installed. The IR installation provides an PowerShell script that can be used to create an automated connection.

For scale-up/down, you'll have to run some script that scales your vm. In an IaaS solution (f.e.) Azure VM, that should be doable with an API call to change your VM.

For both cases you'll have to have some kind of montitor in place that monitors the IR loads and makes changess as needed. I think the measures provided in the Data Factory should do. Maybe you can use Log Analyics to monitor the loads.

I'm curious about your use case for this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just for scaling out/in since the VM must be restarted if you are scaling up/down, which causes downtime and job failures etc.

At a high level this solution requires just 3 simple things:

1. Azure Metric Alert that fires when Scale-Out should occur (VM Start)
2. Azure Metric Alert that fires when Scale-In should occur (VM Deallocation)
3. Logic App that is triggered by Azure Alert and actually executes the Start/Stop of the VM, along with any other automation associated with this (eg posting to a Teams channel when Scale in/out occurs)

Here are more of the details surrounding how we setup the conditions for the alerts, but the main thing to keep in mind is (IR CPU %, IR queue length, Number of Nodes, and possibly IR Memory)

**Scale-Out**

[image: Scale-Out Conditions]

**Scale-In**

[image: Scale-In Conditions]

**Actions for Alerts**

As you can see below we have the alert triggering 1 Logic App, using the payload that is passed to the Logic App, you can determine if the Logic App should be starting the VM, or stopping the VM. (As well as any other additional actions)
[image: Action Group]

**Logic App**

[image: Logic App Development]

There is a small chance that due to timing (and depending on how many ADF's the IR is shared to), that pipeline activities could be sent to Node 2 at the same time a deallocation command is sent to the VM for Node 2. I have not seen this as of yet, but adjusting the alert conditions based on your need could help avoid this. Feel free to play around with the conditions of the alerts, granularity, thresholds, etc. This is not a one size fits all solution.